# Unterschied zwischen Wirbel und Strudel

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, archaism

Vor einigen Tagen bekamen wir einen Lesetext, in dem über Müllstrudel im Meer aufgeklärt wurde. Aber eine hat Wirbel als Ersatzwort vorgeschlagen.

Ich will den Unterschied zwischen Wirbel und Strudel genau wissen. Welches Wort wird wofür genutzt?

Comment: Siehe https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wirbel und https://www.dwds.de/wb/Strudel. Der Wirbel beschreibt eine Kreisbewegung. Beim Strudel kommt der Aspekt einer Abwärtsbewegung hinzu.

Comment: Compare [Strudel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strudel_(Physik)) and [Wirbel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirbel_(Str%C3%B6mungslehre)) at German Wikipedia. In English, one means vortex and one means whirlpool, similar but not the same. English WP also has [Gyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_gyre) which is more specific. See also [Plastikmüll in den Ozeanen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastikm%C3%BCll_in_den_Ozeanen).

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Worin besteht das *eigene* Verständnis von Wirbel & Strudel?

Comment: (Ich mag Strudel gerne essen - der geht dann auch abwärts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sowohl "Wirbel" als auch "Strudel" haben eine Reihe von verschiedenen Bedeutungen. Ein "Strudel" kann beispielsweise auch [etwas zum Essen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strudel_(Gericht)) sein. "Wirbel" hast Du [in Deiner Wirbelsäule](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirbel_(Anatomie)), oder [bei einigen Musikinstrumenten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirbel_(Musikinstrumentenbau)).

Wenn es um spiralförmige Strömungen in einer Flüssigkeit geht, sind die beiden fachlich nicht leicht zu trennen. In der allgemeinen Umgangssprache steht bei einem "Wirbel" jedoch mehr die kreisförmige Bewegung im Vordergrund, bei einem "Strudel" eher der Sog nach unten.

Comment: Ein "Wirbel" kann im Übrigen sowohl horizontal als auch vertikal sein. "Strudel" (außer die, die man essen kann) sind meistens horizontal.

Comment: Strömungen: Ich denke bei Wirbel eher an Luft und bei Strudel an Wasser.

Comment: @mic Du hast wahrscheinlich einen am Hinterkopf. Sind deine Haare luftig? ;)

Comment: @tofro Sie strömen jedenfalls nicht ;-)